# How can I determine what parts of my android app code require which permissions

Tags: android, permissions

I'm just trying to justify the permissions that my app requires and realize that I can't remember why I needed **android.permission.READ_LOGS**

I can't seem to figure out which classes I use need this permission. I've commented out the permission and the app builds fine. However it builds fine if I remove all permissions. Running it crashes for some of those missing permissions, however I can't figure out which function uses the READ_LOGS permission.

Is there something in android studio that will flag missing permissions if you comment out ones you need? Or some cross reference of classes to permissions?

I really don't want to ask users for permissions that are not needed nor justified at least.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using any **critical** Permission then android studio will definitely point out by showing error that `permission is missing for function`.

If you are specifically asking about **android.permission.READ_LOGS** so this permission **allows an application to read the low-level system log files.** Means for the devices when you want to read the log then this is used.

Other way is you can check the [Official Doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html) of permission that which permission is used for which purpose so you can match it with set in your **Manifest** file. Keep the one you need and remove the one you dont need. But in coding it ll just point for the **Critical permissions** otherwise it ll give  error when you are executing your app during testing.

Hope you got the answer. If any doubt then you can comment below.

Comment: I'm not getting any errors or warnings in android studio. So I suppose none of my required permissions are "critical".

Comment: I'm not getting any errors or warnings in android studio. So I suppose none of my required permissions are "critical". I've been able to figure out why I need all my permissions, except for READ logs. I tried to search the api docs but didn't find which classes use this permission. I'll check your link above when I get out of this children's concert I've been rail roared into. :(

Comment: When you use Log.e/v/ or any other that is also using this permission as security exception